# Pass a user defined object to ASP.NET Webmethod from jQuery, using JSON

Tags: asp.net, json, jquery, webmethod

I am trying to pass in some simple JSON to an ASP.NET 4.5 Webmethod from jQuery.  And it is not working quite the way I want it. It works if I accept the inputs as separate parameters:

```cs
[WebMethod]
public static Address GetJSonAddress(string name, string street)
```

But if I try to take it as an object it does not work, what gets passed in is simply null:

```cs
[WebMethod]
public static Address GetJSonAddress(Address newAddress)
```

I have tried Webmethods, Pagemethods, WCF using DataContractJsonSerializer...nothing.  The Address class is decorated appropriately with Datamember/DataContract.  The properties are matched including case.

The jQuery, in which I have tried all manner of passing in the data including wrapping it in an Address object...if I do it any other way than what I have the Webmethod is not called and I get error 500:

```js
Save2 = function () {
var address = { prefix: GLOBALS.curr_prefix };

$('input[id^=' + GLOBALS.curr_prefix + '],select[id^=' + GLOBALS.curr_prefix + ']').each(function () {
       address[this.id.substr(4)] = $.trim($(this).val());
})

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/WebServices/Insert",
    data: JSON.stringify(address),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data, textStatus) {
        console.log(data, textStatus);
    },
    failure: function (errMsg) {
        MsgDialog(errMsg);
    }
});
}
```

Eventually I will have to do this with 121 input strings, and really don't want to have a method with 121 parameters.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you use `data: { newAddress: JSON.stringify(address) }` ?

Comment: The Webmethod is not called and I get error 500 at the browser.  The POST looks ok:  {'Address':{"name":"name","street":"street","city":"city","zip":"11111"}}

Answer (score 46):

I quickly set up this project and I was able to successfully call my web method, please adjust your code accordingly. Make sure your **class property names are the same** as the ones that you pass through JavaScript.

**Webservice**

```
    public static Contact getContact(Contact cnt)
    {
        cnt.name = "Abijeet Patro";
        cnt.phone = "Blah Blah";
        return cnt;
    }
```

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var cnt = {name:'Hello',phone:'Hello'};
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Default.aspx/getContact",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({'cnt':cnt}), // Check this call.
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
            }
        });
    });
```

**Class**

```
public class Contact
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
}
```

---

[image: Web Service Called]

---

[image]

You can grab the project from [here](https://github.com/Abijeet/blog-projects/tree/master/JsonBasedWebMethod). Also please use fiddler or Chrome to monitor AJAX requests/responses. I've added an image to show how to monitor AJAX requests using Chrome. Fiddler is even better and more detailed.

---

[image]

Answer (score -1):

`I am not aware of ASP.` But in Ruby on Rails we are using the below procedure. My form having nearly 20 fields. Through `serializeArray();` I can send all the input field values to controller. Like

Your `HTML` should be look like

```
<input class="input" id="violation_date" type="text" name="violation_date" value=""/>
```

`"name"` field is mportant here.

```
var form = $("form#driver_info_form").serializeArray();
var hsh = { }
$.each(form, function(i, e) {
            hsh[e.name] = e.value
        });

var jqxhr = $.post("/app/DriverInfo/save_driver_info", {
            hsh: hsh
        }, function() { });
```

On controller side we can get param like

```
{"hsh"=>{"violation_date"=>"date", "violation_time"=>"time", "violation_day"=>"week", "username"=>"name", "address"=>"address", "city"=>"city", "state"=>"state", "zip"=>"", "driver_lic_number"=>"123324", "radio_commercial"=>"Yes", "age"=>"", "birth_date"=>"", "sex"=>"", "hair"=>"", "eyes"=>"", "height"=>"", "weight"=>"", "race"=>""}, "accident_check"=>"false", "misdemeanor"=>"false", "traffic"=>"false", "non_traffic"=>"false", "commercial"=>"Yes"}
```

From this we can access the values.

I hope this will give some guideline to you.

Comment: What kind of guideline should this give to OP? He asked a specific question to asp.net and you answer how you would do it in a completely different environment.