# Can I pass dynamic parameter parameter from jquery to WebMethod?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod, anonymous-types

I have 3 parameters that I am passing to `WebMethod` but I don't want them to pass as separate 3 parameters. Then I know solution is to pass object but that object must have structure in C#. Is there any other way so that I don't need to build a class and pass parameters in anonymous one? like `var` or `dynamic`?

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18078957/pass-a-user-defined-object-to-asp-net-webmethod-from-jquery-using-json/18079544#18079544

Comment: @KaushikMaheta thanks for the comment. I know it is the way but here I have to define structure of class, I am finding the way to pass ANONYMOUS one. :)

Comment: What's wrong in defining a class? As far as I know you can't use `var` here. You can use an string array though depending upon the type of data you want to send.

Comment: Nothing wrong, I did that indeed. Just wanted to know alternative to reduce typing efforts ;)

Comment: you can use the word `dynamic` and send the object without class structure

Comment: Thanks, I will consider your advise.