# Calling a C# webmethod from Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to call a server side function from ajax but keep getting this error

> Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027name\u0027.

here is the js code

```
var obj = { name: name, company: company, country: country, email: email, msg: Msg }
var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "ContactUs.aspx/SendEmail",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    data: json,
    dataType:"json",
    success: function (data) {
        var a = 3;
    },
    error:function(a,b){
        var a = 43;
    }
})
```

and here is the c# webmethod

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public static string SendEmail(string name, string company, string country, string email, string msg)
{
    return string.Empty;
}
```

the names are identical between the js and c# vars and all of my vars have values.

thanks in advance

Comment: You are doing a POST but the method looks like its a GET?

Comment: No. that was me tring to fix the problem, it should be GET

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18078957/pass-a-user-defined-object-to-asp-net-webmethod-from-jquery-using-json/18079544#18079544). Pass the entire object.

Comment: I don't think you need to stringify obj

Comment: I think a webmethod must be POST. here is a quick example of one https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

Comment: orignially o used post but it kept giving me this error:
 An attempt was made to call the method \u0027SendEmail\u0027 using a GET request, which is not allowed.
 so i switched to get

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "ContactUs.aspx/SendEmail?name=" + name + "&company=" + company + "&country=" + "&email=" +email + "&msg=" + Msg,
    dataType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        var a = 3;
    },
    error:function(a,b){
        var a = 43;
    }
}) ;
```

Since its a GET type of request you need to pass required values for webmethod parameter in query string. you cant use `data` parameter for this as GET type of request has no payload.

Comment: I think Akshey might be correct.  I would recommend using POST instead of GET, if possible, to avoid this limitation.  For one thing, some web servers will not handle very long URLs correctly, so if you have a large amount of data in the URL, it is possible that the web server might truncate it.