# Ajax cannot call webform's webmethod in asp.net and C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

Here is my Ajax function:

```
function createSalesInvoice() {
  var SalesInvoice = {};
    SalesInvoice.PaidAmount = $("#textbox1").val();
    SalesInvoice.RemainingAmount = $("#textbox2").val();       
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/AjaxRequestToServer.aspx/createSalesInvoice", //URI   
        data: '{SalesInvoice: ' + JSON.stringify(SalesInvoice) + '}',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            bootbox.alert("Item Added Successfully", function (e) { });

            GetSalesInvoiceItemsList();
            $("#hdfFlag").val("false");
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
        }
    });
}
```

I can't call my `[webmethod]`. all values from textbox returns correct. I want to insert those values in table.

```
[WebMethod]
        public static int createSalesInvoice(SalesInvoiceEntity SalesInvoice)
        {
            int i = SalesInvoiceManager1.createSalesInvoice(SalesInvoice);
            return i;
        }
```

Comment: did you add [WebMethod] attribute in your createSalesInvoice()?

Comment: @HamedJavaheri yes.. plz see edits in question my webmethod

Comment: have you checked your data property is proper?

Comment: are you using ScriptManager in your page?

Comment: @HamedJavaheri No. i dont use any ScriptManager

Comment: try:  JSON.stringify({ SalesInvoice: SalesInvoice })

Comment: data: '{SalesInvoice: ' + JSON.stringify(SalesInvoice) + '}', - should be proper in string format

Comment: In you browser(Chrome) hit F12 and then monitor in network tab for errors.

Comment: @HamedJavaheri no any effect. Same problem

Comment: @HamedJavaheri  in network tab icant found any error and also createSalesInvoice my method mame is also not display there in network> File. Tab

Comment: @HamedJavaheri How to find error here?

Comment: plz make your method without parameter (c# and js) and check if it called? also check url is right. hope it helps.

Comment: It shows error in network> Response tab " is not a valid value for Int32."

Comment: @DinkarVeer You can debug and for reference purpose. You can set each property value as valid value. and then see the ajax call. It looks like your object aceepts INT32 and you have assign string value. You parseInt  function before assigning Textbox value to javascript object property

Comment: @SanketPatel yes Sanket. Thanku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to check the parameter passed in **data**

```
 SalesInvoice.FinalAmount = $("#txtGrandTotal").val();
 SalesInvoice.PaidAmount = $("#txtTotalPaid").val();
 SalesInvoice.RemainingAmount = $("#txtTotalRemAmt").val();
```

If above parameters are in integer as In webmethod parameter - (SalesInvoiceEntity SalesInvoice) then should be converted as int by

```
SalesInvoice.FinalAmount = parseInt($("#txtGrandTotal").val());
```

and also value must not be blank rather 0.

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
 data: '{SalesInvoice: ' + JSON.stringify(SalesInvoice) + '}',
```

This should be

```
data: JSON.stringify({'SalesInvoice':SalesInvoice }),
```

Your Javascript function should be like below, Only one line is changed. 
And a javscript object name is changed to "SalesInvoiceJS" for easy difference only.

```
   function createSalesInvoice() {
  var SalesInvoiceJS = {};

    SalesInvoiceJS.FinalAmount = $("#txtGrandTotal").val();
    SalesInvoiceJS.PaidAmount = $("#txtTotalPaid").val();
    SalesInvoiceJS.RemainingAmount = $("#txtTotalRemAmt").val();
   // alert(SalesInvoiceJS.TotalInvoiceValue); ----------------This alert is working fine and return all above values correct.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/AjaxRequestToServer.aspx/createSalesInvoice", //URI   
        data: JSON.stringify({'SalesInvoice':SalesInvoiceJS }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            bootbox.alert("Item Added Successfully", function (e) { });

            GetSalesInvoiceItemsList();
            $("#hdfFlag").val("false");
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
        }
    });
}
```

Reference : [From this place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18078957/pass-a-user-defined-object-to-asp-net-webmethod-from-jquery-using-json/18079544#18079544).

Comment: @DinkarVeer can you set default correct values to SalesInvoiceJS object instead of textbox values? and test function.

Comment: You're going to have to learn how to use your browser's tools to debug. Learn how to look for JavaScript errors and monitor network traffic. Check your function is actually getting called etc.