# No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.String' during JSON deserialization calling c# webmethod

Tags: c#, json

I'm getting this error 'No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.String' during JSON deserialization' when I try to call my C# webmethod from JavaScript.

C#

```
using System.Web.Services;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

[WebMethod]
public static string insertValues(string param)
{
    JObject data = JObject.Parse(param);
    //data manipulation starts here

    return "finished";
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({ type: 'GET', url: 'https://url_returning_json_object',
   success: function (data) {
         PageMethods.insertValues(data, function (ex) {
                console.log(ex);
          });
   }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are passing `param` as string rather than as a object / class?

Comment: @mjwills since I'm passing data from a classic ASP web app to the C# server side, I think the only way to achieve this is using an string. I just wanted to give the solution to anyone who faces the same problem.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18078957/pass-a-user-defined-object-to-asp-net-webmethod-from-jquery-using-json/18079544#18079544 .

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution: I needed to 'stringify' my json object before calling the webmethod.

```
$.ajax({ type: 'GET', url: 'https://url_returning_json_object',
   success: function (data) {
         //NEW LINE ADDED
         retData = JSON.stringify(data);

         PageMethods.insertValues(retData, function (ex) {
                console.log(ex);
          });
   }
});
```