# How to use Ajax with Multi Array Objects by JSON from client to server side (C#)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, ajax

How can I do with following questions?
1. Front-end site question is how to transfer Object-Array to JSON?
2. Back-end site question is how to get the JSON data from front-side?

### Question 1:

> how to make a data parameter in the AJAX?

```
 var vItems = [];
        var vItem = new Item('1', '11');
        vItems.push(vItem);
        vItem = new Item('2', '22');
        vItems.push(vItem);    

 function Item(Key,Val) {
        this.Key = Key;
        this.Val = Val;
    }

 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ".............",
            data: ????????????????????  ,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);  
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
```

### Question 2:

> How to make a correct parameter with C# function

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
 public static string xxx(?????????)
 {    
        return "";
 }     
 public class VItems
 {
        public string Key;
        public string Val;
 }
```

PS: Please I've to use the same class between front-side and back-side like

Front-Side

```
         function Item(Key,Val) {
                     this.Key = Key;
                     this.Val = Val;
                 }
```

Back-Side

```
         public class VItems {
                     public string Key;
                     public string Val;
                 }
```

By the way, this issue isn't duplicative 
[URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18078957/pass-a-user-defined-object-to-asp-net-webmethod-from-jquery-using-json)
because it is just only one array-object, I need to handle multiple
data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass a user defined object to ASP.NET Webmethod from jQuery, using JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18078957/pass-a-user-defined-object-to-asp-net-webmethod-from-jquery-using-json)

Comment: @Liam I've seen it  before,however it is just for one array object , i need to handle multiple Array-Objects

Comment: @Liam Thank very much for your help, I'm not sure how to send two arrays Json to server side (not correct JSON.stringify( vItems ))  and how to get data from Client side (not correct public static string xxx(VItems Items) )

Comment: @Liam Thank again,you have given me a lot of a great information, now I've tried and solved my problem, it is a little difference from your answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've solved my problem and hopefully it can help anyone who has the same problem

```
var vItems = [];
        var vItem = new Item('1', '11');
        vItems.push(vItem);
        vItem = new Item('2', '22');
        vItems.push(vItem);


$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "xxxxx.aspx/xxx",
            data: JSON.stringify({ Items: vItems } )  ,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {                        
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });

      [WebMethod]
        public static string xxx(List<VItems> Items)
        {    
            return "";
        }

        public class VItems
        {
            public string Key;
            public string Val;
        }
```

Comment: @Liam Thank again,you have given me a lot of a great information, now I've tried and solved my problem